# Issue with jQuery nextUntil

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Can someone help me out with this? I just want "faqanswer" to display when "showfaqanswer" is clicked for each one. I don't see what's wrong with the PHP and jQuery code. Thanks for the help!

```
<?php query_posts("cat=17&posts_per_page=7&offset=7"); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<p>
<a href="#" id="showfaqanswer"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
</p>

<div id="faqanswer"><?php the_content(); ?></div> 

<?php endwhile; ?>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('#showfaqanswer').click(function(){
$('#faqanswer').nextUntil('#showfaqanswer').show();
});
});
```

Comment: Id must be unique. change id to class and try

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) on the `nextUntil` selector: it gets *siblings*, so it won't select anything if it has no siblings.

```
$('#showfaqanswer').click(function(){

    // get the parent of the current #showfaqanswer, select until the the next p-tag
    $(this).parent().nextUntil('p').show();
});
```

Comment: the above code seems to work but only on the first element. It seems suresh.g is correct about needing to have unique ids? The php code is a WordPress loop for getting posts from a certain category

Comment: @cpcdev yes, definitely use unique IDs ... not sure why this doesn't work though

Answer (score 0):

we need to use class. Because id must be unique.

Please try this :

```
<?php query_posts("cat=17&posts_per_page=7&offset=7"); ?>
<?php $i=1; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<p>
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $i;?>" class="fanswer"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
</p>

<div id="faqanswer<?php echo $i;?>" style="display:none;"><?php the_content(); ?></div> 
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.fanswer').click(function(){
var id = $(this).id;
$('#faqanswer'+id).show();
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the above code... but no luck :(. Any other suggestions?